# Insert Rows based on DateDiff (fill in inserted rows with dates)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556073/insert-rows-based-on-datediff) to insert new rows

but the problem is when there is the same **start date** as **end date** I get the

> Error 1004

- can you help modify the VBA to skip those lines that produce the Error?
- is there an easy way how to fill in the column B (marked red) the consequential dates to complete the table (one day per line)?

[image: example of table]

```
Start Date  End Date    Hours   Type
02-01-18    02-01-18    8   one day
04-01-18    04-01-18    4   half day
05-01-18    06-01-18    16  multiple days
07-01-18    10-01-18    16  multiple days
11-01-18    11-01-18    8   one day
```

**UPDATE:**

[image: issue with VBA calculations from the bottom up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an if command to check to see if the dates match, then only run the check if they dont. the code will now add every subsequent date between the start and end date

```
Public Sub AAA_Format()

Dim i As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim startrow As Long, insertedrow As Long
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With Worksheets("Data")
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count


    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1 '' starts at bottom and goes up, that way inserting rows doesn impact it
        'checks to see if 2 values are the same
        If Not Cells(i, "B") = Cells(i, "C") Then
        Debug.Print Cells(i, "B")
        Debug.Print Cells(i, "C")

            d = DateDiff("d", .Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "C")) '' find differene
             Debug.Print d
              insertedrow = i + d
            .Rows(i + 1 & ":" & insertedrow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If

        For j = 1 To d
            .Cells(i + j, 2) = .Cells((i + j) - 1, 2) + 1
            .Cells(i + j, 3) = "what ever you want to calc end date as"
            .Cells(i + j, 4) = "what ever you want to calc hours as"
            .Cells(i + j, 5) = "what ever you want to calc day as"
        Next j

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

To insert a column you can use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").EntireColumn.Insert
```

and to add formula to it you can use

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '' this find bottom row by starting on very last row of sheet and moving up until it finds a cell with a value in it
Range("D2").Formula = "=IF(C2>0,C2,C1+1)"'' you might need to change , for ; depending on your language pack
Range("D2:D" & LastRow ).FillDown
```

Comment: thank you David, indeed, the If is simple

but I get issues with the j function (startrow on line 37) - could you help me review the whole code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7HNkq (PS. my source data file has the start date - that I want to complete with sequential dates - in column B and variable number of rows)

Comment: Happy to help, Ive updated my code to fix the inserted row issue (my fault i missed it). by starting at the bottom and looping up you avoid the issue of inserting rows. Looks like i got the wrong end of the stick ad was trying to look up values from another table. in my new example it will add he rows then add missing days incrementing one at a time. i dont know how you calc the end date, hours or day type so just dropped some text in. replace that with the formula you want

Comment: David, thanks, I surely like to idea of starting from the bottom, however, there is an issue with some of the calculations and I just can't make out why, because some of them are ok, and some are not, I am adding a screenshot in my original post of when I run the macro on my sample data
-- first 40 hours event (from the bottom) is calculated just fine (green)
-- next 2 days event (16 hours) the calculation is fine but the original date (in column B) is overwritten with the End date (red)
-- another one (yellow) is again overwritten in col.B by a weird number (why 27 Jan instead of 29 Jan??)

Comment: Hi, i see what you mean, im not quite sure why the issue is happening. At a guess it might be the resizing insert. Ive updated my code and tried changing it to a standard row insert and it seems a lot more stable for me. Give it ago and let me know

Comment: David, it didn't help, there are still the same errors in calculations. But I found out a much easier approach : once I have inserted the correct number of empty rows, I can just insert an extra column, then go from the top downwards with this formula =IF(C2>0;C2;C1+1) that will fill in the dates from the start days as necessary ... :-) now I just need to figure out how to transport this to VBA so i don't have to create extra columns manually...

Comment: Hi, glad you found a way that works, I've added how to inset a column and how to fill it with the formula you need (you might need to change columns and worksheets ect)